# Deserialize from different class, same project

Tags: c#, serialization

I have  a C# solution with projects A and B, among others, where B has a reference to A. A contains a serializable class ClassA. B contains two classes ClassB1 and ClassB2. From ClassB1 I serialize an object of type ClassA, saving it in Folder1. Folder1 belongs to the solution, but not to projects A or B. If I try to deserialize the object from ClassB1 it works fine. Then from ClassB2 I desperately try to deserialize the serialized object. I get an access denied to Folder1 error message.

Any ideas  WHY this error occurs and how can I solve it ?

UPDATE. In project B, I just serialized an object of type ClassB1 from its constructor. I cannot deserialize this one either from ClassB2! All the serialized files are in Folder1 from the main project of the solution, project C. Whenever I deserialize from the same class that serialized an object, it works like a charm. But when trying to deserialize from a different class, it fails, on the same folder Folder1.

Comment: Is this a puzzle test?

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's clearer.

Comment: What's the error message? :@

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an access denied exception then I would say it is some file locking issue. Do you nicely close all the file streams you open?

Comment: This was my thought too, but when I serialize, I close the filestream. I stress the fact that I can deserialize the object without problems from a method of the same class that serialized it. Problems occur when I try to deserialize it from a different class, as explained in the question.

Comment: Mistery solved, path to file was wrong in the deserializing classes!